# HOWTO avoid duplicated insert with unique key in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I know Core Data makes NSManagedObjectId as its primary key.

Now, in such a scene, **msgId is unique for message records**.

`Thread A` attempts to insert a message with msgId 1001 into the context. Before the insert, `thread A` has tried to find the message with key `msgId` and value `1001`. Nothing was found, so it performs the insert action.

In the meanwhile, `Thread B` is doing the same thing for message with msgId `1001`.

So, as the time ------------->

`Thread A` : find  -->  insert  -->  save

`Thread B` :       find  -->  insert -->  save

Both the thread A & thread B has their own context, they find, insert and save, so the message with msgId `1001` was possibly inserted twice and save to the disk repeatedly.

Maybe I can use serial queue `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` to make the `find-insert-save` operation one by one to avoid this problem. But I wonder that if there is any other way to do that, such as a primary key? Yes, I know Core Data is not a database, but a object-graph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason Lee,

I solve this problem by performing all of my inserts on a background queue and catching the -didSave notifications to start surfacing items in the UI. This guarantees single access to items as they are created. After that, multi-threaded access is always permissible against a known unique ID.

Andrew